# How to prevent handlebars partial from reloading on every express route?

Tags: express, handlebars.js

I created a website using handlebars and express. My nav element is a handlebars partial that is used across all 4 different express routes. The problem is, when the user navigates to the a different page, the nav reloads every time and it causes the styling of the nav partial to be off for a brief moment. So, how do I prevent a handlebars partial from reloading on each express route?

Comment: I don't think people will be able to help unless you show the relevant code and situation.  Theoretical questions are massively harder to figure out exactly what you're doing or what the problem is.  Show enough of your real code/HTML for people to know how to reproduce the problem and then the question becomes real rather than a theoretical question we have to guess about.

Comment: Theoretically, this sounds like a caching problem with your CSS, but since you don't show any of the real HTML/CSS, that's just a wild guess.  Navigating to a new page MUST re-render your partial into the next page so it's unclear what else you're expecting.